# https address bars for windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

This is for WindowsPhone. How I can show an address bar for a xaml web control in an app studio webapp only in https:// secure pages ..?

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe `WebView.NavigationStarting` event, then use `WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs.Uri` to get protocol scheme. If the scheme equals to "https", your can set your custom xaml address bar in code-behind.

Reference: [WebView.NavigationStarting Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-CN/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigationstarting.aspx)